# Angular. @Input change detection performance

Tags: angular

I have a legacy code with some strange things. there are two classes (`Base` and `Child`, `Child` is derived from `Base`) with several equvalent properties

```
export class Base {
@Input('prop1') prop1: string;
@Input('prop2') prop2: string;
...
}

export class Child extends Base {
@Input('prop1') prop1: string;
@Input('prop2') prop2: string;
...
}
```

I don't think it's was a good idea to keep the same properties in both classes from the very beginning but may be there was a reason for a previous developer I don't know about. I'd like defenitely to remove Child version of properties (because they should be derived from Base) and as my team is fighting for performance at the moment - it will definitely motivate me for refactoring if you tell me such a duplication has performance issues.
I don't know if using 'prop1' inside @Input for the same property name has side effects on performance detection also.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think the previous developer did this because until angular version 4 input property inheritance was not supported. https://github.com/angulardart/angular/issues/231 

For a current version of angular the input properties on the base should be sufficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are suggesting will not impact performance in a visible manner.
However, you can do it a much cleaner way.

You shouldn't be setting the input names if they are equal variable names. There is no added gain from doing this and reduces readability.

It would be better if it was more straight forward:

```js
export class Base {
@Input() prop1: string;
@Input() prop2: string;
...
}

export class Child extends Base {
@Input() prop1: string;
@Input() prop2: string;
...
}
```

Some points:

- If the base class is always extended and never used on its own, you can remove the `Input` decorator. Since you are declaring the properties in the child class, they are being overridden there with the `Input` element. As it currently stands, you are declaring in the `Base` class only to be overridden in the `Child` class again with the same decorator. I'm not stating that you should delete the property in the `Base` class, only that you should remove the decorator like so:

```js
export class Base {
prop1: string;
prop2: string;
...
}

export class Child extends Base {
@Input() prop1: string;
@Input() prop2: string;
...
}
```

This will not break your code (at least it doesn't in more recent angular version).

- The github you linked is not for an `Angular` issue but an `AngularDart` issue. The two are not the same, so be cautions.
- If you want to improve the performance of your application, you should have a look at changing your `ChangeDetectionStrategy` from `Default` to `OnPush`.
  There are plethora of blogs stating that this is very helpfull for performance and explain how its done.